# How to Style CSS Checkboxes with Font Awesome

Tags: html, css, checkbox, font-awesome

I am trying to style my checkboxes with Font Awesome, the checkboxes are auto generated from a plugin I"m using with wordpress I have a mockup of what everything looks like in JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bBPY5/1/

It seems to be something a bit wrong with my CSS but I can't figure out what.

```
<div id="sidebar-cards-archive">
<ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-12">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ofcards-rarity[]" value="12">Common (223)</label>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-14">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ofcards-rarity[]" value="14">Epic (40)</label>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-11">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ofcards-rarity[]" value="11">Free (83)</label>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-15">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ofcards-rarity[]" value="15">Legendary (36)</label>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-13">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ofcards-rarity[]" value="13">Rare (84)</label>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
 @import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);
 #sidebar-cards-archive ul li {
     list-style: none;
 }
 /*** custom checkboxes ***/
 input[type=checkbox] {
     display:none;
 }
 /* to hide the checkbox itself */
 input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
     font-family: FontAwesome;
     display: inline-block;
 }
 input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
     content:"\f096";
 }
 /* unchecked icon */
 input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
     letter-spacing: 10px;
 }
 /* space between checkbox and label */
 input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
     content:"\f046";
 }
 /* checked icon */
 input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
     letter-spacing: 5px;
 }
 /* allow space for check mark */
```

Comment: have you looked at either of these: http://jsfiddle.net/8PYJg/, and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223615/how-to-use-font-awesome-for-checkboxes-etc?

Comment: Yes, and the CSS doesn't seem to work with my HTML, I can't adjust the HTML since it is outputed by a plugin.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, that CSS you have won't work because its wrong.

Why? Because when you say "input + label", you should have an HTML markup like the one below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ofcards-rarity[]" value="15">
<label>Legendary (36)</label> //You will be querying this label css with input + label
```

See, `<label>` is placed immediately after `<input>`. You can confirm this [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)

Now in your case, your `<input>` was a child of you `<label>`, looking like this:

```
<label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ofcards-rarity[]" value="15">Legendary (36)
</label>
```

To query that, you could have done something like this:

```
label>input[type=checkbox] {

}
label>input[type=checkbox]:checked {

}
```

And since you wanted to put something beetwen them, you add this to your css:

```
label>input[type=checkbox]:before {

}
label>input[type=checkbox]:checked:before {

}
```

I've adjusted it for you. It's not the easiest/cutest way to implement it, but at least works with your current HTML.

Here's the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bBPY5/4/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I greatly appreciate you helping me with this.

Comment: Does not work in Firefox

Answer (score 4):

I created checkboxes and radio buttons using Font Awesome. The ones I found online had something or the other missing. I needed ones that could be scaled and I didn't want any unclickable gap between the checkbox and its label.

Here are links to the [repository](https://github.com/maxweldsouza/font-awesome-controls) and the [demo](http://maxweldsouza.github.io/font-awesome-controls/)

Comment: The problem with your solution is it is not accessible.

Answer (score 4):

No JavaScript but small html manipulation like adding label with "[for](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_label_for.asp)" attribute.   so that when ever click on label checkbox click will trigger.
[image]

```css
    .form input[type="checkbox"]{
  display:none;  
}
.form input[type="checkbox"] + label.fa {
    color: #88E2E2;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.form input[type="checkbox"]:checked +label.fa{
    background: #fff;
}
.form input[type="checkbox"] + label.fa:before {
     display:inline-block;
     content: "\f096";
     cursor:pointer;
}

.form input[type="checkbox"]:checked +label.fa:before{
    content:"\f046";
    position: relative;
    left: 2px;
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <form class="form">
    <input id="check_1" type="checkbox"/><label class="fa" for="check_1"></label>
          <input id="check_2" type="checkbox"/><label class="fa" for="check_2"></label>
    <input id="check_3" type="checkbox"/><label class="fa" for="check_3"></label>

    </form>
```