# Add FontAwesome checkbox with <label> surrounding input

Tags: html, css, checkbox, styling

I'm trying to get a FontAwesome checkbox to show in the particular instance when the label wraps the input. However I'm not sure why it's not working.

This link has the same question, however the answer provided doesn't work.
[How to Style CSS Checkboxes with Font Awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305780/how-to-style-css-checkboxes-with-font-awesome)

Any ideas as to why the CSS provided in the answer in the link above doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Because `input` is one of those elements that ***cannot have content***, and thus, don't take `:before` or `:after`, as this relies on `content: ...;`.

### Explanation:

Check this example:

```
<p class="my-element">some text</p>
```

If you apply

```
.my-element:before {
    content: "My element: ";
}
```

the browser will render it as

```
<p class="my-element">My element: some text</p>
```

So `p` can have something *inside* - `content`.

Now where is the browser supposed to put "My element: " in the following case?

```
<input type="checkbox" class="my-element" />
```

This element cannot have anything *inside* it, so there is nothing that `content: "My element: "` could possibly be added to.

## Solution

So if you want to apply styles using `:checked`, and you want to hide the checkbox, yet still need it 'clickable', you need to attach a `label` to it **not by wrapping the checkbox**, but by using the `for` attribute of the `label` element, which must match the `id` attribute of the checkbox. Place the `label` **after** the input in the HTML, and you can use `:before` or `:after` on the label element (which **can** have content):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a1" style="display: none;" />
<label class="checkmarklabel" for="a1"></label>

:checked + .checkmarklabel:before {
    /* put the required CSS for your font's checkmark here */
}
```